# Wrong reading order in Narrator

Tags: c#, wpf, accessibility, narrator

I've got a problem with Microsoft Narrator.

I've got a WPF fragment like this:

```
<Window
    x:Class="InlineEditbox.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Narrator test" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <TextBlock>
        <Run xml:space="preserve">I want to pay </Run>
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <TextBox Width="70" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">0</TextBox>
        </InlineUIContainer>
        <Run xml:space="preserve"> % more</Run>
    </TextBlock>
</Window>
```

The text is displayed correctly; however the Narrator reads it this way: "I want to pay percent more, zero" instead of the expected "I want to pay 0 percent more".

Am I doing something wrong? The Narrator could have read the whole text just consequently. Is there a way to work around the problem without the need to change the actual text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from WPF team member:

WPF supports a text control that can have child controls intermixed with its text. The UI Automation tree does not. There is no way describe to automation clients where the child edit control lives within the parent's text. WPF cannot easily fix this - it's a limitation of the automation architecture.

To workaround, one can put the text into separate controls to describe the order in a way that translates to automation:

```
<TextBlock>I want to pay</TextBlock>
<TextBox> 0 </TextBox>
<TextBlock>% more</TextBlock>
```

Thx, Rob Relyea

WPF Team

Comment: Thanks a lot for an authoritative answer!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use narrator, it's an extremely basic screen reading program and is not generally used by people who need to use a screen reader on a daily basis. See the following question for reccomendations on screen readers to use. [Which screen reader would be best to test site accessibility and how to configure that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323683/which-screen-reader-would-be-best-to-test-site-accessibility-and-how-to-configure)

Comment: I don't use the Narrator myself; however I need to implement accessibility features in my code, Narrator support being one of them :-(

Comment: In that case I would suggest you talk to who ever is in charge of feature requirements and explain to them that narrator support is not duable. If you have to support a screen reader I'd suggest NVDA from http://www.nvda-project.org since it's free and open source.

Comment: Working in a large commercial company, it's pretty complicated. The PMs think that the users have mostly Narrator on their systems, so the task is to support explicitly Narrator. I wonder if there is somewhere usage statistics on accessibility support software (I'll try to find it in Google.)
Anyway, thank you for the suggestion!