# How do you test if your HTML page or application is accessible?

Tags: html, accessibility

After adding accessibility to my HTML page, how would one test if it is working correctly? I would like to hear how it sounds and navigates for someone who is using a screen reader.

Let me put it another way, when you build a web page you preview it in a browser(s) to see if it looks and behaves correctly. When you add accessible to that same web page how to do you know it's working correctly?

Comment: For HTML, just paste the URL in browser. The page would be rendered.

Comment: Please don't just vote to close the question! If it's unclear tell me what's wrong with it.

Comment: You could try and find a screen reader emulator, if you don't have a device available to hand.

Comment: What do you mean by add accessibility? Could you edit you question and clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a quick spot check, you can use [WebAIM's WAVE](http://wave.webaim.org/), which tells you the big errors. If you wish to dig deeper, you both need an understanding of WCAG 2.0, and assistive technology. WebAIM has a [checklist for WCAG 2.0](http://webaim.org/standards/wcag/checklist), which would be the next step, along-side using assistive technology. People tend to only think assistive technology = screen readers, but this is incorrect. There are many different types of assistive technology. I recommend reading through the note at the top of the checklist.

[NVDA](http://www.nvaccess.org/) is a free screen reader

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you might be SOL:

[Site accessibility: what screen readers, etc to test against, and how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709488/site-accessibility-what-screen-readers-etc-to-test-against-and-how)

[Screen Readers For Testing Website Accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796887/screen-readers-for-testing-website-accessibility?rq=1)

If you're really looking for a semi-automated solution, you might be able to stitch together Selenium (or similar) and a screen reader emulator (as described in the second linked post) to pull down an audio file of the screen reader, then submit the text to Mechanical Turk [for transcription](http://amyhacks.wordpress.com/2012/04/13/dirt-cheap-audio-transcription-with-amazon-mechanical-turk/), then `diff` your site text against the transcript you get to see how confused the writer was. It would cost a few bucks, but potentially save you more-expensive programmer hours.

Comment: Would the downvoters like to explain? I linked questions to indicate that fully automated testing (what I assume the OP was after) is more or less impossible, and suggested an alternative.