# winforms - Can't get windows narrator to read message box content

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox, narrator

I have a simple message box:

```
MessageBox.Show(this, "bla bla bla", "banana man", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, options);
```

And for some reason I don't manage to get the windows narrator to read its content ("bla bla bla").
Any idea how I can solve this?

Thanks,
Li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Narrator is a very basic screen reader and not intelligent enough for many cases. I am not sure whether it is possible at all to support narrator to read this. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323683/which-screen-reader-would-be-best-to-test-site-accessibility-and-how-to-configure) may give you more details.

See [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows7/Hear-text-read-aloud-with-Narrator) if it helps you.

[image]